# From php file call another php file by giving it also a parameter

Tags: php, post

I will explain with a simple example:

myphp1.php:

```
$html = get_html("myphp2.php", "parameter1"); //pseudocode
```

myphp2.php

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      echo $_POST["parameter1"];
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

So basically the `$html` will hold the myphp2.php html output. Can I do that?

Comment: You could just use php include or require.

Comment: You have to use `cURL` to send `POST` parameters. Read the documentation on PHP cURL, then show us what you've tried.

Comment: ok I will read it and then edit my question

Comment: You could make a very simple templating system so you can require the file and pass some variables to it as an array.

Comment: you can use [**Artax**](http://rdlowrey.github.io/Artax/examples/) instead curl .. its better and simpler

Comment: @xoemab Simply use Ajax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking to interpret the php script, and save the output, you should send a new request.

Using PHP5 you can do this without curl:

```
$url = 'http://www.domain.com/mypage2.php';
$data = array('parameter1' => 'value1', 'parameter2' => 'value2');

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$html = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

var_dump($html);
```

Comment: It load the html but php is not executed. Instead of generating html I see my php code.

Comment: This code requests the PHP script just as a browser would, if your web server is not evaluating the code then another problem exists. My concern is that the code runs on the first page, but not on the second? They exist on the same server right? This behavior would be expected with a simple include() or require() but should not happen here.

Comment: the problem was that I was not adding "http".. Now it working

Answer (score 2):

Sending an HTTP POST request using file_get_contents is not that hard, actually : as you guessed, you have to use the $context parameter.

There's an example given in the PHP manual, at this page : [HTTP context](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) options (quoting) :

Detailed example

```
$url = "http://example.com/submit.php";
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'var1' => 'some content',
        'var2' => 'doh'
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Basically, you have to create a stream, with the right options (there is a full list on that page), and use it as the third parameter to file_get_contents -- nothing more ;-)

As a sidenote : generally speaking, to send HTTP POST requests, we tend to use curl, which provides a lot of options an all -- but streams are one of the nice things of PHP that nobody knows about... too bad...

Comment: Your example is like David Houde but its not working for reason look at his answer comment

Comment: What you want @xoemab. give me your requirement clearly

Comment: @xoemab so only we help you. tell me the reason why you are trying this flow

Comment: I see from you code that you understood what I want.. the $result give the html output but it not executing the php code so instead of php generated html I actually see my php code

Comment: If that is the case, then the problem doesn't exist with the code but with the server.